# Comparing Excel value alphabetically

Tags: vba, macos, excel-formula

I am writing a VBA code , where I need to match a row with column value alphabetically.

Example: like in `Sheet1.Cell(1,1) = Apple` and `Sheet2.Cell(2,1) = Apple`, I want to match this two values, but the vba code is not working.

I am using this code :

```
If StrComp(Worksheets("Fixed").Cells(5, 1), Worksheets("Fixed").Cells(5, 5)) = 0 
   Then MsgBox (Worksheets("Fixed").Cells(5, 6))
End If
```

Regards
Prakash Singh

Comment: you need `StrComp(Worksheets("Fixed").Cells(5, 1), Worksheets("Fixed").Cells(5, 5),vbTextCompare)` as per [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function)

Comment: Yes, I do followed the same syntax

Comment: If StrComp(Worksheets("Fixed").Cells(5, 1).Value, Worksheets("Fixed").Cells(5, 5).Value, vbTextCompare) Then   { I am getting Syntax error while using above code}

Comment: ok sorry, have you got that all on one line?  you need a new line after `Then` and before `End if` by previous comment probably doesn't change the outcome for this code (to undate)

Comment: if I am using this<<<<If (StrComp("Microsoft", "MiCrOsOfT", 0)) Then>>>> its working,   But If I am using <<<<If (StrComp(Worksheets("Profile").Cells(1, m).Value, "MiCrOsOfT", 0)) Then>>>  its not working

Comment: change to `If (cstr(StrComp(Worksheets("Profile").Cells(1, m).Value), "MiCrOsOfT", 1)) Then` should work

Comment: StrComp(CStr(Worksheets("Fixed").Cells(1, 5).Value), CStr(Worksheets("Fixed").Cells(1, 6).Value))   , its not working

Comment: `StrComp(CStr(Worksheets("Fixed").Cells(1, 5).Value), CStr(Worksheets("Fixed").Cells(1, 6).Value), 1)`

Comment: Your original code works if you move `Then` to the previous line and the values in `A5` & `E5` match - it gives the value in `F5`.